# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, version-control, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I've added a gem 'koala' to my Gemfile and seems to have thrown gem versions out of whack when I run the 'bundle install' command:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
faraday (0.6.1)

In Gemfile:
koala (~> 1.2.0beta1) depends on
  faraday (~> 0.7.4)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

How can I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Delete the contents of `Gemfile.lock`, and run `bundle install` again.  That's been working for me.

Comment: I was unable to install rails_admin, and this just fixed it for me too.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: This will spontaneously upgrade a whole bunch of your gems. It's better to do them one at a time and test, as updating gems can introduce bugs

Comment: if someone has error `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll"`, just delete version part of your project `Gemfile` , i mean change `gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0.0"` to `gem "jekyll"`

Comment: Coming from JS world, I had used fixed versions for all my gems and all hell broke loose. I wanted to configure Jekyll with Github Pages... The trick was to remove all fixed versions and remove the lock file then run `bundle` again

Answer (score 35):

Did you run `bundle update` as the error message points out?  `bundle install` handles changes to the Gemfile and `bundle update` upgrades gems that are already managed by Bundler.  The Gemfile.lock file locks in version numbers, `bundle update` will update any of those that aren't directly specified in your Gemfile (like `gem 'rails', '3.0.9'`).

Deleting the Gemfile.lock will work, but running `bundle update` is better.

Answer (score 7):

You can't simply delete you `Gemfile.lock` if that is a solution then why `Gemfile.lock` is exist in the first place, you code depend on the versions locked in this file, try to only update the Gem which cause the conflict by using `bundle update gem_name` and you have to check the ReadMe if any changes needed to work with the new version otherwise you are breaking your code or others code.

Answer (score 5):

I found that by removing the specified version of rails solved the problem for me .... 
instead of:

```
gem rails, '4.0.4'
```

I did

```
gem rails
```

followed by deleting the Gemfile.lock and re-running *bundle install*

Answer (score 3):

If deleting `Gemfile.lock` doesn't work there is another possibility:

It may be possible a gem you are depending on has inadvertently included its own Gemfile.lock in its .gem file. The solution is to update the offending gems to not include a Gemfile.lock, rebuild and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to go to your `Gemfile.lock` and delete all references to the offending gem (in this case the `faraday` gem).
Then run `bundle install` and it'll update the `Gemfile.lock` to have compatible versions of the gem where it needs.
If you want to be extra safe you can go to the `Gemfile` and specify the versions of the gems you want before doing this.

This was the only way I was able to get `bundle install` running for one of the systems that I'm maintaining.
This system has a lot of old gems in its dependencies (58 gems at the time of writing) and so `bundler` has a hard time coping with it.
If I delete the `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` it'll blow up with multiple `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem xxxxxx`  errors.
If I run `bundle update` it would also blow up with multiple `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem xxxxxx` errors.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: Removing `Gemfile.lock` will have new entried to different gems. This might not be acceptable in your project. Your team or lead will not allow this.

**If you are working on legacy codebase, for example Rails 3.2 or similar**
In case you hit this kind of errors,

see the last line of `Gemfile.lock` which seems like

```
  whenever (~> 0.9.4)
  wicked_pdf (= 1.1.0)
  will_paginate (= 3.1.8)
  wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge (~> 0.12.4.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.6
```

now install the version of `bundler` mentioned in the file. In my case its`1.16.6`.

```
gem install bundler -v 1.16.6
```

now remove the older version. How?

```
$ gem uninstall bundler

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. bundler-1.16.6
 2. bundler-2.1.4
 3. All versions
> 2
Successfully uninstalled bundler-2.1.4

$ bundle -v     
Bundler version 1.16.6
```

Now it will install successfully