# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "colorator"

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I have a problem with bundler not being able to resolve a jekyll dependency, colorator. I've tried `gem install colorator` and then `bundle update` again, but to no avail.

Output:

```
Madss-MacBook-Pro:my-website madsoestergaard$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "colorator":
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (>= 3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      colorator (~> 0.1)

    jekyll (>= 3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      colorator (~> 0.1)

    jekyll-sitemap was resolved to 0.12.0, which depends on
      jekyll (~> 3.3) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
        colorator (~> 1.0)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll":
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (>= 3.0)

    jekyll-polyglot (= 1.2.4) was resolved to 1.2.4, which depends on
      jekyll (>= 3.0, ~> 3.1)

    jekyll-prismic was resolved to 0.1.1, which depends on
      jekyll (~> 3.0.0)
Madss-MacBook-Pro:my-website madsoestergaard$
```

Also, when I try to `jekyll --version`, I get this error. I think it could be related, not sure though.

```
Madss-MacBook-Pro:my-website madsoestergaard$ jekyll -v
/Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:203:in `rescue in start': Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll": (Bundler::VersionConflict)
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (>= 3.0)

    jekyll-polyglot (= 1.2.4) was resolved to 1.2.4, which depends on
      jekyll (>= 3.0, ~> 3.1)

    jekyll-prismic was resolved to 0.1.1, which depends on
      jekyll (~> 3.0.0)
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:199:in `start'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:181:in `resolve'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:250:in `resolve'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `specs'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:48:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Users/madsoestergaard/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
Madss-MacBook-Pro:my-website madsoestergaard$
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll", '>= 3.0'
gem "jekyll-sitemap"


group :jekyll_plugins do
   gem "jekyll-polyglot", '1.2.4'
   gem "jekyll-prismic"
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I should point out that I've already [tried the solutions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144846/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem)

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I solved it myself. I found out that `jekyll-prismic` was the plugin causing trouble. I removed it, and everything installs as it should again.