# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack", compatible actionpack installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and trying to install rails 4.1.6 environment on macOS 11.5.2 Big Sur

When I run bundle install, I encounter this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-datatables-rails (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)

    rails-api was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.2.11)

    redis-rails was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-actionpack (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 4.0, < 7)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.3, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_api (= 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

    carrierwave was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)

    squeel was resolved to 1.2.3, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_api (= 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    carrierwave was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)

    redis-rails was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-activesupport (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3, < 7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "coffee-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      coffee-rails (>= 3.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    koala was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      faraday

    sentry-raven (= 2.6.0) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
      faraday (>= 0.7.6, < 1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
        json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)

    koala was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      json (>= 1.8)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      mime-types (>= 1.16)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mime-types

    rest-client (~> 1.7.2) was resolved to 1.7.3, which depends on
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)

Could not find gem 'mimemagic (= 0.3.0)', which is required by gem 'paperclip (~> 4.3.2)', in any of the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
        rack (~> 1.5.2)

    acts_as_api (= 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      rack (>= 1.1.0)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      resque (>= 1.26) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
        sinatra (>= 0.9.2) was resolved to 1.4.8, which depends on
          rack-protection (~> 1.4) was resolved to 1.5.5, which depends on
            rack

    redis-rails was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-actionpack (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        redis-rack (>= 1, < 3) was resolved to 2.0.6, which depends on
          rack (>= 1.5, < 3)

    request_store (= 1.4.1) was resolved to 1.4.1, which depends on
      rack (>= 1.4)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      resque (>= 1.26) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
        sinatra (>= 0.9.2) was resolved to 1.4.8, which depends on
          rack (~> 1.5)

    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0) was resolved to 3.7.2, which depends on
        rack (> 1, < 3)

    devise was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
      warden (~> 1.2.3) was resolved to 1.2.7, which depends on
        rack (>= 1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6)

    bootstrap-multiselect-rails was resolved to 0.9.9, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.0.0)

    bootstrap-tooltip-rails was resolved to 0.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap-slider-rails (= 9.2.0) was resolved to 9.2.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.0)

    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)

    data-confirm-modal (= 1.2.0) was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.1.0)

    font-awesome-rails was resolved to 4.7.0.7, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 7)

    jquery-datatables-rails (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      jquery-rails was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)

    jquery-tablesorter was resolved to 1.27.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2)

    momentjs-rails (= 2.15.1) was resolved to 2.15.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      railties (= 4.1.6)

    rails-api was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2.11)

    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 5.0.6)

    jquery-datatables-rails (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      sass-rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        sprockets (> 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)

    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        sprockets-rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tzinfo":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
        tzinfo (~> 1.1)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      rufus-scheduler (~> 3.2) was resolved to 3.8.0, which depends on
        fugit (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.6) was resolved to 1.5.1, which depends on
          et-orbi (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.8) was resolved to 1.2.4, which depends on
            tzinfo
```

I have all the gems installed in correct versions, here is the output of my gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.6)
actionpack (6.1.4.1, 4.1.6)
actionview (6.1.4.1, 4.1.6)
activemodel (4.1.6)
activerecord (4.1.6)
activesupport (6.1.4.1, 4.1.6)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
builder (3.2.4)
bundler (default: 1.17.2)
CFPropertyList (2.3.6)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
crass (1.0.6)
csv (default: 3.0.9)
date (default: 2.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.3.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
erubi (1.10.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.15.3)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
i18n (1.8.10, 0.9.5)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
jquery-datatables-rails (3.3.0)
jquery-rails (3.1.5)
json (default: 2.1.0, 1.8.6)
libxml-ruby (3.1.0)
logger (default: 1.3.0)
loofah (2.12.0)
mail (2.7.1)
matrix (default: 0.1.0)
mini_mime (1.1.1)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
minitest (5.11.3)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
nokogiri (1.10.1)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.1.0)
pg (1.2.3, 0.21.0)
power_assert (1.1.3)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
rack (2.2.3, 1.5.5)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.1.6)
rails-api (0.4.1)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
railties (4.1.6)
rake (12.3.2)
rdoc (default: 6.1.0)
redis (4.4.0)
redis-actionpack (5.2.0)
redis-activesupport (5.2.1)
redis-rack (2.1.3)
redis-rails (5.0.2)
redis-store (1.9.0)
rexml (default: 3.1.9)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
sass-rails (6.0.0)
sassc (2.4.0)
sassc-rails (2.1.2)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
shell (default: 0.7)
sprockets (3.7.2)
sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.13)
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
test-unit (3.2.9)
thor (1.1.0)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tilt (2.0.10)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
tzinfo (2.0.4, 1.2.9)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zeitwerk (2.4.2)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

As per what I can figure out, action pack 4.1.6 will suffice to the conditions required by `jquery-datatables-rails`, `rails`, `rails-api`, `redis-rails` & `sprockets-rails`
Can someone help me figure out why I'm facing these issue? Everything was working perfectly until last week I did a brew update. Please help

Comment: Here's a related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144846/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem have you tried running `bundle update` or deleting `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Yes, did ```bundle update```, didn't work. Then tried deleting ```Gemfile.lock```, no luck!

Comment: what is your ruby version inside your project `ruby -v`? Are you using `rvm` or `rbenv`? Perhaps you have installed 2 versions of ruby on your machine, which is common. Each one will have a set of gems